# Jquery if clause

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help to write a if statement using jquery. So if results.d.ProductName is empty do not show `$(prdHtml).html(html);

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Services.asmx/GetProduct",
    data: '{ "fieldName": "' + id + '"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
success: function(results) {
        var html = '<h3>' + results.d.ProductName + '<h3>'
                    + '<a href=""' + results.d.Url + '</a>';
        $(prdHtml).html(html);
```

Comment: This question looks incomplete.  Did you forget something? Can you add a little more detail?

Comment: You do realize jQuery is javascript, right? :)

Comment: ok. Here's the complete code. Sorry for not doing that earlier. Also the answers posted earlier do not seem to work. Not sure if I understand why thats the case.

Sa

Comment: @sa - I still do not understand. Do you mean 'hide' it if it is empty?

Comment: Hi Karim,
Yes. Actually I have a custom function HideIfEmpty() that I can use. So if these values do not exist. It should just call this function and that will hide it.

Comment: @sa - you can use jQuery's hide() method. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

```
success: function(results) {
        if(results.d.ProductName.length) {
            var html = '<h3>' + results.d.ProductName + '<h3>'
                        + '<a href=""' + results.d.Url + '</a>';

                $(prdHtml).html(html);
        } else {
            $(prdHtml).hide();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
success: function(results) {
if (results.d.ProductName!="") {
        var html = '<h3>' + results.d.ProductName + '<h3>'
                    + '<a href=""' + results.d.Url + '</a>';
        $(prdHtml).html(html);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(results) {
  // should probably test if d exists before testing for productname
  if (typeof(results.d) == "undefined" || typeof(results.d.ProductName ) != "string")
   return;

  ...code
}
```